# Assuming we live in a simulation, does quantum mechanics exist so that freewill can be computed?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, simulated-universe

There is a chance that we live in a simulation. If we do, that might explain some of quantum mechanics.

Everything is made up of 1 of 2 states. For example, you will, or will not, go to the movies today. Even if that decision required multiple other decisions to be made (e.g., is it raining, are there any good movies playing?), the finest decisions (even on a biological level - the neuron), is in 1 of 2 states.

However, in quantum mechanics, for some unknown reason, these smallest levels are in both states at the same time. But when the state is observed by a conscious observer, it immediately becomes 1 of the 2 possible states. How does a nonliving being (I.e., these quantum states) know when we're observing it?

My idea is that if we are indeed living in a simulation, randomness caused by freewill is simply too difficult to compute, and hence is not computed until a conscious entity reads the value. This is kind of like lazy loading in video games.

The simulation we live in would be running on an extremely powerful computer which could predict pretty much anything given an initial condition, such as where a particle of sand will be several years from now. But since we have freewill, there are infinite combinations of events which could occur. This is why quantum states exist: to allow the computer to be able to simulate our universe.

I am aware that quantum mechanics hasn't been shown to have effects on the macroscopic world yet. I think this idea of mine is silly, but can't seem to put my finger on what exactly is wrong with it. What do you think? Note that I'm not suggesting that the existence of quantum mechanics is evidence for the simulation theory. I'm wondering if this is a correlation.

Comment: there are a lot of misconceptions about physics in your question. I suggest you post this on the physics SE to get them cleared up first and then take a second shot at asking your question here. PS I worked with a Hundi Kamath 50 years ago in California

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction